# Manager doesn't work for Abstract Models

Tags: django, django-models

I am getting this error, however I'm not sure where `BasicModel` is from.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/seanna/pdenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 264, in __get__
    self.model._meta.object_name,
AttributeError: Manager isn't available; BasicModel is abstract
```

This is the error I'm receiving when I try to add a model via admin or via the app itself.

```
from shared.utils import *

class Forum(BaseModel):
    title = CharField(max_length=60)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

This is where I use the BaseModel
which in shared.utils:

```
class BasicModel(Model):
    class Meta: abstract = True
    obj = objects = Manager()

    def update(self, **kwargs):
        for k, v in kwargs.items():
            setattr(self, k, v)
        self.save()

BaseModel = BasicModel      # TODO: rename all views to BaseModel
```

I'm not sure why `BaseModel = BasicModel` and what that actually does but this gives me errors with adding models.

Comment: That traceback is produced by what action?

Comment: If it works by inheriting BasicModel, why don't do this:
`from shared.utils import BasicModel as BaseModel`

Comment: And if you are trying to do `BasicModel.objects...` or `BaseModel.objects...` it won't work, because Abstract models are not to be "queried", as they don't really have a database.

Comment: @LorenzoPeña I was trying to create a new UserProfile which also inherits from BaseModel within the admin page; I'll try what you suggested though

Comment: It also gave me problems just accessing the admin page when I tried the import BasicModel as BaseModel; I'm only querying objects like Forum that inherited from BasicModel